# SQL Query Diffrences In vs EXISTS

Tags: mysql

I thought below 2 queries are working same. but returning rows are very different. Could you please explain me why those are different?

1.

```
SELECT de.dept_no from dept_emp de where de.dept_no
IN (select d.dept_no from departments d where d.dept_name='Finance');
17346 rows in set (0.02sec)
```

2.

```
SELECT de.dept_no from dept_emp de where EXISTS
( select d.dept_no from departments d where d.dept_name='Finance');
331603 rows in set (0.83sec)
```

Comment: Your exists query isn't correlated.

Comment: Oh I got this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EXIST does a true false comparison, the second query, the subquery part is always true if you have at least one department named 'Finance' so it returns all the rows  in `dept_emp` it. Assuming at least one department named finance exist, the query is equal to

```
SELECT de.dept_no from dept_emp de where TRUE
```

If you want a faster way of achieving what's in the first query you should use a JOIN

```
SELECT de.dept_no FROM dept_emp de INNER JOIN departments s
on de.dept_no = d.dept_no
WHERE de.dept_no;
```